# How to ask for a file on the cmd to be used on the java application

Tags: java, cmd

I am currently writing a java application to automate a broken link test. What I want to do is when I write the command

`java test.jar`

the user must write

`-f file.txt`

in the same comand line, as to include the file that contains all the url's pages to be tested. Also, I want the user to optionally include a file where all the url's to be ignored are found there. For example

`-ignore ignoreUrl.txt`

Comment: I wonder what is the reason for downvoting this question by people?...

Answer (score 0):

This is the library you will find very useful:
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/

In your case it would be:

```
private Options createOptions() {
    Options result = new Options();

    Option file = Option.builder("f")
            .required()
            .argName("f")
            .desc("Name of the file.")
            .hasArg()
            .build();

    Option ignore = Option.builder("i")
            .argName("ignore")
            .desc("File name to ignore")
            .hasArg()
            .build();

    result.addOption(file);
    result.addOption(ignore);

    return result;
}


public boolean parse(String[] args) {
    if (args == null || args.length == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();
    try {
        commandLine = parser.parse(createOptions(), args);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Note that inside parse() method, you have a reference to "commandLine". From there you can use:

```
commandLine.getOptionValue("f")
```

to get a file name and so on.